# Regex Pattern - extract number from string

Tags: regex

Having very little knowledge on Regular expression has forced me to seek expert help on making a Regex pattern for extracting the number **63600** out of the following string :

```
Amount - < span style="color:#333">63600</span>
```

Comment: String split and int.parse is an option

Comment: What have you tried so far? What regex engine are you using? What have you tried other than regex (which shouldn't be needed here at all)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596251/parse-integer-from-string-containing-letters-and-spaces-c-sharp

Comment: what language are you using and for what purpose..!

Comment: the string is actually a part of a larger html markup and I am trying to extract this particular number which of-course may vary. the pattern is then passed on to the C# Regex class which then matches it against the provided html.

Comment: I have the following line of code which should return me the extracted number: return new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(html).Groups[i].Value.Trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the only number in that string just use `\d+`. `\d` matches one digit, `+` means that it must be 1 or more digits.

Edit:

OP edited a question. Now, if it's the only number between tags, you can handle it in that way:

```
>\d+<
```

Answer (score 1):

just simple

```
>(/d+)<
```

can do the work.